# Python Script to get text from excel file and write on an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an excel file that contain data.I want to write that on an image that have same name as an excel file.Little bit of help will be highly appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import glob
import os

images=glob.glob("E:\Images/*.jpg")

for img in images:
    images=Image.open(img)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(images)
    font=ImageFont.load_default()
   
    text=" Sensor Longitude Sensor Latitude"

   
    draw.text((0,240),text,(250,250,250),font=font)
    images.save(img)
I have that code but it just write same text on all images.I want to write a unique text on an image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Care to provide WHAT unique text exactly?
Right now it's the same text, because your `text` is just a hardcoded string.
You can use f-string to customize it:

```
name = "Bob"
text = f"Hi {name}"
```

Will give you
text = "Hi Bob"